# How to install the old java version in PPA?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I want to install JDK8-build#151 from PPA. The is a version at
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/?type=ppas&vals=122

[image]

The folllowing commands always install java8-build 201 into my machine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

How can I install the build 8u151?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install <package name>=<version>`

Answer (score 0):

Do apt update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then check if the desired version '8u151' is showing up:

```
sudo apt-cache policy oracle-java8-installer
```

If you are able to see your package, then install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer=<the desired version>
```

Comment: Here is the result of command #2
[oracle-java8-installer:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8u201-1~webupd8~1
  Version table:
     8u201-1~webupd8~1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status]

Comment: I have to download the JDK8-buil152 to my local computer then upload it to my server because Oracle does not allow any download their JDK via wget. Then I use the script at site: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/02/install-any-oracle-java-jdk-version-in.html